# Click event doesn't work on my custom entity which appears when my NFT marker is recognized

Tags: javascript, aframe, ar.js

I would like to redirect the user on another website when he clicks on my custom 3D object which appears when my NFT marker is recognized

I used a basic onclick event on my a-entity with a call to a function which redirect with a "window.location.href" but it works not very well : the redirection is done 1 time out of 10.

I also tested to create an addEventListener with click event + the method to register an AFRAME component with redirection but any test weren't working fine.

This is an example of my code :

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@1c2407b26c61958baa93967b5412487cd94b290b/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-orbit-controls@1.2.0/dist/aframe-orbit-controls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@^4.0.0/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function onClickVoiture() {
            window.location = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .arjs-loader {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            z-index: 9999;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .arjs-loader div {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1.25em;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="arjs-loader">
    <div>Loading, please wait...</div>
  </div>
  <a-scene
    vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
    renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;"
    embedded
    arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam;debugUIEnabled: false;"
  >
   
    <a-nft
      type="nft"
      url="https://my-web-app.azurewebsites.net/images/tracteur-haut"
      smooth="true"
      smoothCount="10"
      smoothTolerance=".01"
      smoothThreshold="5"
    >
      
      <a-entity position="0 0 0" scale="80 80 80" animation="property: rotation; to: 360 0 0; loop: true; dur: 10000" gltf-model="url(https://my-web-app.azurewebsites.net/3D-objects/cube-violet-mickael-threejseditor/cube-violet-mickael-final-threejseditor.gltf)" onclick="onClickVoiture()">
          </a-entity>
    </a-nft>
  
    <a-entity id="camera" camera="userHeight: 1.6" look-controls orbit-controls="autoRotate: false; target: 0 1.6 -0.5; enableRotate: true; maxPolarAngle: 180; minDistance: 0.5; maxDistance: 180; initialPosition: 0 5 15" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Can you help me please ?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug that's mentioned by the author [here](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/issues/66). But someone seems to have hacked some way out of the issue: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/148#issuecomment-606470700. I havent tried out the solution but it might help you.